# Segmented Active User Counts Doesn't Add Up to the Total Active Users (GA4)

Tags: dashboard, metrics, google-analytics-4

I'm encountering an issue while using Google Analytics 4 (GA4) for analyzing user data.

I have defined different user segments - UserGroup1, UserGroup2, and UserGroup3. When I check the active users for each segment individually, the numbers are as follows:

UserGroup1: 5 active users
UserGroup2: 4 active users
UserGroup3: 2 active users

[GA4 custom dashboard displaying 6 active users in total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjX4v.png)

I would expect the total count of active users to be the sum of these individual counts, i.e., 11 active users. However, GA4 reports only 6 total active users.

I've confirmed that there is no overlap of users between these segments - since one user cannot belong to two different user groups. Also, I see that the data is not sampled. Despite this, the total doesn't add up correctly. Additionally, I've thoroughly reviewed the definition of active users in GA4 and checked the implementation of my segments.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I see the same issue when using default channel grouping splits. If I use total users or active users then the sum of the values is greater than what is listed as the total. If I use New Users I do not see this issue. 
Did you ever find out the reason?